# Need to disable Javascript within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web

I'm building a portfolio site; it's a one pager with a lightbox functionality. So, basically I am showing HTML5 ads I have built, which I am embedding in an iFrame. These ads have audio, so when I close out of the lightbox the audio continues to play. Now I have tried different methods but have been unsuccessful. I have tested one method which worked, where I removed the src of the iFrame (ONE iFrame which I assigned an ID). Like so:

```
**HTML:**
<iframe id="test" class="iframe-src" src="media/rogue-nation/300x250-progressive-post/index.html" width="300" height="250" style="border:none"></iframe>

**JavaScript:**
var test;
var lightbox;

test = document.getElementById('test');
lightbox = document.getElementById('lightbox');

lightbox.addEventListener("click", closeLightbox, false);

function closeLightbox() {
...
test.src = "none";
}
```

So...my questions are:

- What is the "best" way to apply this method to each iFrame depending on which one was interacted with (tried, getElementsByClassName but was unsuccessful)
- Is there a way to disable the scripts within an iFrame so I don't have to use this method, as I am not so crazy about it
- Also, please don't post jQuery solutions or advise me to use jQuery, as it will not be helpful because I am writing plain JavaScript

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you hosting the content in your lightbox on the same domain? (looks like it as you're using "media/..." as iframe src)

Comment: Yes, I'm loading HTML5 ads I have organized in directories into these iFrames. (I'm loading the index.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your iframe content lives on the same domain it is easy. You could do something like this when your lightbox closes:

```
function closeLightbox() {
    // get the iframe which is playing audio
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    // make sure you can reference the audio element on the iframe
    // e.g. with an id.
    var sound = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('sound');
    sound.pause();
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    // then close the lightbox with some other code
    // ...
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](https://output.jsbin.com/tulubefuko)**